# How do I update my .RProfile on RStudio Server

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I installed the free rstudio server on a digital ocean server. I got everything going, but I wanted to customize my .RProfile.

I ran:

```
candidates <- c( Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE"),
                 file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "etc", "Rprofile.site"),
                 Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER"),
                 file.path(getwd(), ".Rprofile") )

file.edit(Filter(file.exists, candidates))
```

Which opened the file in RStudio, but it said I didn't have the rights to overwrite it. I shouldn't have to be `root` to update the RProfile since different users in theory could have different RProfiles.

Does anyone know how to update .RProfiles on R Studio Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command finds an *existing* .Rprofile to edit. You probably want to create a *new* .Rprofile for your user account. This should do the job:

```
file.edit("~/.Rprofile")
```